# Casting light on an object

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light, cantrips

If I cast the light cantrip on an object and the object breaks while the spell is still in effect is each piece of the broken object still lit?  Could the pieces be carried in different directions?  Would the amount of light decrease based on the size of the piece?

Comment: Thanks. You're right. It has been answered. I didn't see that when I searched.

Comment: No problem! There’s no penalty for unintentionally asking the same question again. In fact it’s good: you get a quick answer, and now there’s a higher chance that future searches will find this or that wording. Thank you for contributing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules aren't specific enough for an accurate answer. I would not expect that each piece of the object would still emit light since that would allow you to break an item and use it as though you had dozens if not hundreds of light spells active. There are really only two light levels in this edition of D&D: bright and dim. You couldn't expect one large fragment to be him and a smaller fragment to be extra dim.

It would come down to the DM's decision. The two most likely results I would expect are:

1. The light spell ends since the object it was cast on no longer exists per se.
2. The largest fragment of the broken item continues to have the light spell active while the other fragments stop glowing.